# filter on array by matching id to route.params.id not working

Tags: arrays, filter, nuxt.js

I am trying to filter an array by matching an id to route.params.id and push the result to a new array. 
fetching data and filter below but the results are not pushed to the arrModelSize array.

```
  async created() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/items")
    const data = await response.json()
    const { size, submitDate, project_id } = data
    data.forEach(d => {
      const { size, submitDate: date, project_id } = d
      this.arrModelSize
        .filter(item => {
          return project_id.id === this.$route.params.id
        })
        .push({ date, total: size });
      console.log(size, project_id.id, this.$route.params.id)
    })
  }
```

The console log at the end shows matching results I would expect, but does not get assigned to the new array

[image]

any insight is appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Do you want to add `size` and `date` to the object where `project_id.id` === `this.$route.params.id`?

Comment: yes that is correct - the new array will include size and date where the id's match. in the image above 3 items would be added to the array.